# Property 'value' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['value']

Tags: angular, typescript

how to fix this problem.

in console have two type of error

1)Object is possibly 'undefined'.

=>error in code  -->this.navigationExtras.state.value = item;

2)Property 'value' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['value'].

=>error in code     -->this.navigationExtras.state.value = item;

**list.component.ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationExtras,Router} from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
 item:any;
 navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
   state: {
     value :null
   }
 };
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onGotoEdit(item:any):void{
    this.navigationExtras.state.value = item; //error 
    this.router.navigate(['edit'])
  }

  onGotoSee(item:any):void{
    this.router.navigate(['details'])
  }

  onGotoDelete(item:any):void{
    alert('Deleted');
  }

}
```

**edit.components.ts**

---

error in this file -->Type '{ [k: string]: any; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'null'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'null'.

error in code -->   this.value = navigation?.extras?.state

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.scss']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {
  value = null;

  constructor(private router :Router) {
    const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
    this.value = navigation?.extras?.state;
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: update just remove null from (value=null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't know what type of item is being passed to `onGotoEdit()`? Would be nice to type check it. Let's add an if check, to make sure we have this obj where we are tying to assign item.

But the index signature error is fixed by doing what it says in the error: `.state['value']`, not `.state.value` (or `.state?.value`).

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  item:any;
  navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    state: {
      value : null
    }
  };

  constructor() {
    this.onGotoEdit('something');
    console.log(this.navigationExtras)
  }

  onGotoEdit(item:any):void {
    if (this.navigationExtras.state) {
      this.navigationExtras.state['value'] = item; 
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-295kkz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: i try above code but still getting error (error-->TS4111: Property 'value' comes
from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['value'].)

Comment: Please try again and look at the demo.

Comment: thanks  error solve  for this component (list.component.ts)but where i get value of this compenent  in  (edit.compopent.ts) error occur

Answer (score 0):

In case of form or Router state/extras its wise to use `['square-brakets']` but for other cases I suggest to use tsconfig.json change

```
"compilerOptions": {
//
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
```